# Private source library with public sample app gradle setup

Tags: android, git, gradle

We are developing android library and sources are not opened. However it is distributed over maven repository for client convenience.

We also provide sample app for this library which sources are opened.

We are trying to make setup to achieve that sample app is developed at the same time as library. So it is convenient to debug if needed and modify code on the fly.

So we created two git repositories for app and library. But what is best way to incorporate them. We see next possibilities:

- use maven local with library snapshots
- copy sample app to library as module and at release time merge all changes to sample app repo with updating library dependency from module to artefact from repo
- slight variation of previous use git submodule

None of them looks efficient and elegant. But at the same time things we are building are not unique. I wonder how it is done by others.

I've tried to search libraries on github but all of them are public libraries and sample apps just submodules.

Important note - we are using Android Studio, so minimizing number of opened AS windows is preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create regular multiproject structure but switch between dependencies based on some criteria [19.2. Gradle properties and system properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html). This way sample project on dev machine would have an access to the library project which could be edited and rebuild, but opensourced user of the sample would fallback to maven libary binary dep.

```
multiproject (under git as 3rd project or as part of the library git)
 library (under git)
   build.gradle
 sample (under another git)
   build.gradle (if has libmodule defined use it, otherwise repo artefact)
 build.gradle
 settings.gradle
```

Pseudo code:

```
dependencies {
    compile hasDevMachineBoolean() ? project(':library') 
                                   : "com.packagename.sdk:library:1.0"
}
```